# scroll zoom texto

Tags: bootstrap, scroll, zoom

tengo este código https://codepen.io/c0deish/pen/yiAjo/ que hace un zoom a un texto mientras haces scroll. El tema es que al mommemento aplicarlo al código que tengo no funciona como debería, acaso me estoy perdiendo de algo o estoy olvidando añadir algo más? este es el código de la página

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>D 3.0</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body id="page-top">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">SERVICIOS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">STATEMENT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">CONTACTO</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<header class="bg-primary">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to Scrolling Nav</h1>
        <p class="lead">A landing page template freshly redesigned for Bootstrap 4</p>
    </div>
</header>

<section id="about" class="bg-azul">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="thing">About this page</h2>
                <p class="lead">This is a great place to talk about your webpage. This template is purposefully unstyled so you can use it as a boilerplate or starting point for you own landing page designs! This template features:</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="services" class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto text-center">
                <h2 class="thingm">¿Cómo estás conectando tu audiencia?</h2>
                <div class="espacio"></div>
                <h2 class="thingm">¿Tus acciones de marketing son realmente efectivas?</h2>
                <div class="espacio"></div>
                <div id="scroller">
                    <div class="inner">texto zoom</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="thing">Información de Contacto</h2>
                <hr width="50%" />
                <div class="espacio"></div>
                <!-- <p class="leaf"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>  direccion</p>
        <p class="leaf"><i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i>  telefono 1<br><i class="fas fa-mobile"></i>  telefono 2</p>
        <p class="leaf"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> correo 1<br><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> correo 2 </p> -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white" style="font-size: 0.7rem;">d2018</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</footer>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JavaScript for this theme -->
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

El texto que debe tener el efecto es este:

```
<div class="inner">texto zoom</div>
```

Gracias por su ayuda y su tiempo.

---

Este es el código con los cambios hechos, solo quedaría solucionar el problema del width, apliqué max-width con un valor de 100vw pero no resultó.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>D 3.0</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,900" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body id="page-top">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">SERVICIOS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">STATEMENT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">CONTACTO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<header class="bg-primary">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to Scrolling Nav</h1>
    <p class="lead">A landing page template freshly redesigned for Bootstrap 4</p>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="about" class="bg-azul">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <h2 class="thing">About this page</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a great place to talk about your webpage. This template is purposefully unstyled so you can use it as a boilerplate or starting point for you own landing page designs! This template features:</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="services" class="bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto text-center">
        <h2 class="thingm">¿Cómo estás conectando tu audiencia?</h2>
        <div class="espacio"></div>
        <h2 class="thingm">¿Tus acciones de marketing son realmente efectivas?</h2>
        <div class="espacio"></div>

            <div id="scroller">
        <div class="inner thingm" >Únete a</div>

      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <h2 class="thing">Información de Contacto</h2>
         <hr width="50%" />
        <div class="espacio"></div>
         <p class="leaf"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>  direccion</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="m-0 text-center text-white" style="font-size: 0.7rem;">d2018</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</footer>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JavaScript for this theme -->
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script  src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Este es el js del zoom

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
 var top = $(window).scrollTop(),
  scale = top / 100;
 $('.inner').css({
  'transform':'scale('+scale+','+scale+')','-webkit-  transform':'scale('+scale+','+scale+')'
 });
 });
```

el css del zoom

```
 .inner{
 color: #000;
 font-size:2rem
     }

 #scroller {
 min-height: 300px;
 position:relative;
         }
```

Comment: Hola Jorge. Es necesario que publique el codigo de la pagina con el problema en cuestión, ya que no se puede saber que texto es el que quiere que reciba el zoom.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, ya edité la pregunta y agregué el código de la página. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, revisando su código y el código de la página a la que  me envía su link, noté que para que el efecto funcione necesita especificar un height en los estilos tal y como se hace aquí:

```
#scroller {
  min-height: 1000px;

  position:relative;
}
```

De tal manera que a medida que se hace scroll el tamaño del div valla aumentando.
Al tener un heigth tan pequeño en su página, este devuelve un valor muy pequeño en este cálculo, de tal manera que el texto es inperceptible:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var top = $(window).scrollTop(),
      scale = top / 1000;
  $('.inner').css({
      'transform':'scale('+scale+','+scale+')','-webkit-transform':'scale('+scale+','+scale+')'
  });
});
```

Aquí tienes dos opciones:

1) Darle un height mucho más grande al div con la clase **scroller** tal como se hace en la página de ejemplo que publicó, donde se especifica un **min-height:1000px**.

Aunque supongo que hacer esto destruiría su diseño y no es lo que busca.

2)Cambiar el valor por el que es dividido la variable **scale**:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var top = $(window).scrollTop(),
      scale = top / 100;
  $('.inner').css({
      'transform':'scale('+scale+','+scale+')','-webkit-transform':'scale('+scale+','+scale+')'
  });
});
```

Note que en vez de dividir entre 1000, divido entre 100. Puede jugar con este valor hasta ajustar el tamaño que tomará el div según su conveniencia. 
*Adicionalmente cambié algunas reglas css:

```
.inner{
color: #fff,
font-size:10em
}
```

por:

```
.inner{
color: #000,
font-size:2rem
}
```

Con estos cambios conseguí que el texto pueda tener el efecto que usted deseaba. Espero haber podido ayudarlo. Recuerde puntuar la respuesta como válida para ayudar a otras personas con su mismo problema en el futuro.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Despues de hacer los cambios mencionados ya logro tener el efecto funcionando, lo que si noto es que al momento de hacer el scroll, el width se extiende mostrando obviamente la barra de desplazamiento horizontal, como podría solucionar eso. Gracias.

Comment: Claro, con gusto podré ayudarlo siempre y cuando publique su código completo, para poder revisarlo y sugerirle algún cambio. Pero puede aplicar la propiedad max-width: 100vw en el contenedor que esta teniendo el problema.

Comment: Hola Joel, gracias por tu pronta respuesta, ya agregué el código actual. Te agradezco por tu tiempo.

Comment: De nada. Edite la clase .inner de la siguiente manera:

 .inner{
   top:60%;
   left:50%;
   position:fixed;
 color: #000;
 font-size:2rem
     }


Puede cambiar los valores de top y left según su conveniencia.

Comment: Ahora si, el único cambio que hize fue cambiar position:fixed; por position:absolute; y quedo perfecto. Gracias nuevamente.